# Values changed dynamically by an option (PHP)

Tags: php, html, ajax

I would like to know if I can display values dynamically depending on a selected option without loading the PHP site again without using Ajax ?

```html
                <FORM>
                    <SELECT name="Langage" size="1">
                        <OPTION selected value="en">English
                        <OPTION value="fr">Français
                        <OPTION value="es">Español
                        <OPTION value="de">Deutsche
                    </SELECT>
                </FORM>
```

Can I use only some if php to change these :

```
    <th scope="col"><?php echo T::var1; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo T::var2; ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?php echo T::var3; ?></th>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question? What needs to change and where, depending on what?

Comment: If you want to do anything with this selection in PHP, then you _have to_ send the value back to the server first. If you don’t want to reload the whole page via a normal form submission - then a background request (AJAX/fetch), is basically your only other option. If you don’t want to do that, then you could only do this part purely client-side, using JavaScript - then everything that _could_ potentially be displayed based on the user’s choice, must have been send to the client when the initial page loaded already, and you only decide which of that to display dynamically later on.

Comment: The values (T::var) should be changed instantly when an option is selected. So I have to use Ajax that's it ?

Comment: You mean that the content of the `<th>` elements needs to change?

Comment: yes that's it. Sorry if im not clear !

Comment: If you don't have a large amount of data, then the third approach that @CBroe described could work for you (load all potential values into JS and change the value using the client only, without talking to the server). Otherwise, you'd need AJAX.

Comment: Do you want to it as SPA? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application there is a lot of SPA frameworks.

Comment: The last option would be a websocket https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-websocket-server

Comment: Thanks for all this help. Yesterday I couldn't find how to solve this problem so I went on another thing. I'll take a look at WS. It would be nice for me to learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you want to change the options in a select box based on the selected option from another select box?

If yes, you are looking for Dynamic Dependent Select Box.

This will help you.
https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/